# How to remove URL injection by parameter en masse?

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, url, code-injection

My (wordpress) site was recently the victim of an attack...ended up with around 20,000 injected URLs. I've since cleaned up the site completely, plugged all the holes, and have installed further hardened the files, but I'm still left with all these URLs in the google index & a message on Google that says "This site may be hacked" because of all these spammy URLs. It's just not realistic to be able to go through & add them to the Webmasters URL Remove tool. I've heard the best way is to get them to display 404 (or 403) and they'll naturally fall out of the index.

Here's what I'd like to do, but haven't figured out how to do it yet: I'd like to come up with a way to force any URL with a certain parameter to display a 404 or 403. For example, the below URL is a good representation of the URLs that are currently indexed:

http://mysiteurlhere.com/index.php?free-online-games-with-cash-prizes.html&items=2&pidnum=1568

Both "items" & "pidnum" are parameters that are used in every single indexed URL that I've seen. My question is: would it be possible to single out one of those parameters with some sort of .htaccess statement, and block or force the URL to 404?

(note: I did go through the robots.txt to disallow any further URLs with parameters like these from being indexed...I just don't know how to do the .htaccess method)

Comment: What happens now when you go to this page ? isn't a 404 message showing up ?

Comment: It just displays a copy of the homepage (index.php) now. Before I cleaned it up, it was injecting all sort of spammy content between the nav & body content.

Answer (score 2):

Try with `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)items=.*pidnum= [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]
```

Comment: You test with the same link in your question ?

Comment: Yeah. I just noticed that it drops out the "index.php" part at the beginning, but the URL is still displaying the same as before (a copy of the homepage).

Comment: So in other words, the URL is displayed as:
http://mysiteurlhere.com/?free-online-games-with-cash-prizes_html&items=2&pidnum=1568

Comment: or use `RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [NC,F,L]`

Comment: since it cuts out the index.php part when it loads & the URL begins with /?free-online-games-with-cash-prizes... is there a way to target the question mark portion at the beginning instead? I tried replacing the index\.php with a question mark & I get an Internal Server Error for all pages then...

Comment: Ok just use `RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]`

Comment: Yeah, I did. The only other thing I have in the root .htaccess is the following. Would any of this be messing with it?

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Comment: I do have it at the top

Comment: I tried surrounding it with <IfModule mod_rewrite.c></IfModule>...didn't work either.

Comment: What if I just target one of the parameters...how should that look?

Comment: `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)items= [NC]` for `items`